# Efficient way of validating UDP communication protocol having single Server and multiple Clients

Tags: c, windows, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have developed a single Server/multiple Clients udp application, where Server can handle x number of clients at a time. The Server has x number of threads each thread dedicated to one Client.

The code works perfectly fine. Now I want to check my application for all possible scenarios i.e. validate my application. For this purpose, I need to design a test best.

**Initial Design:**
The test bed I initially designed has following functionalities:

- The Server GUI has a button on it. When the button is clicked, the
  each thread in the Server reads a text file, picks up few bytes of
  the text file, and sends those chunks to its respective clients. The
  thread then picks next chunk of bytes from the text file, sends those
  chunks to the client and so on until EOF is found.
- The Client on the other side keep receiving these chunks of bytes,
  creates a text file, and keeps storing these chunks of bytes in its
  text file.
- When EOF from Server is received, the Client starts sending the
  completely received text file back to the Server over its Socket.
- When the file is completely received back (echoed), the Server then
  compares the two text files, the Sent file and the echoed one. If
  both files are same, the communication process has occurred without
  any fault and the communication protocol is validated.

The above mentioned validation technique (sending the text file, receiving the echoed file and then comparing both) checks the following things:

1. The number of bytes sent = number of bytes receieved.
2. No data is corrupted.
3. The data is receieved in proper order.

If any of the above mentioned three conditions is not fulfilled, that means that there is some error in communication.

Now I have been asked to make changes to this test bead and add more functionlities to it. Does the procedure that I am using actually can check above mentioned 3 conditions in all scenarios?

Are there some other conditions that must be checked besides above mentioned 3 conditions.

What could be other methods of checking communication protocol except the one I desgined i.e. Sending a text file and getting it echoed and then comparing.

I have to implement more functionlities to his test bed for making validation system more efficient or completely replece the above test bed with some better option.

Please help me with your suggestions.

Thanks in advane :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two of your conditions are guaranteed by UDP. Picking "a few bytes", i.e. anything less than 65535 bytes (64kiB isn't really a "few" bytes) will result in a single datagram being sent, and anything larger than that will fail. Though you will not want to max out the largest possible datagram size, as it will incur IP fragmentation (staying below 1280 bytes is a good idea).

You will be able to receive exactly the amount you sent or nothing at all, never more or less. UDP does not guarantee that any datagram that is sent out arrives (it cannot guarantee that, since IP does not), but it does guarantee that the entire datagram arrives as-is -- or nothing. Never anything in between.
It further guarantees that the data inside the datagram matches its checksum (the underlying protocols including IP/ethernet/ATM further do their own checksumming) and thus arrives in the same binary representation as it was sent. In other words, data arrives in order (inside the datagram) and is not corrupted.

It is of course *in theory* possible that a bit error passes all 3 layers of checksums, but this is extremely unlikely and will not happen in practice. Unless you need to guard against someone *maliciously* tampering with packets, you do not need to worry. The kinds of bit errors that happen *accidentially* are reliably picked up by the checksums used in the protocols.
If, on the other hand, you do need to guard against malicious modification of your data, you must add a MAC (or a checksum *and* encrypt the entire packet -- adding a checksum alone is useless).

To ensure that data spanning several datagrams arrives in order, you must add sequence numbers to your packets (in the same manner TCP does). And with that, *you can as well use TCP*, which is likely more efficient and less error-prone. One of the main reasons why one would want to use UDP is normally because in-order delivery and reliability are *not* needed, or sometimes reliability is needed, but not in-order delivery.
In-order delivery is the main cause of TCP's latency during packet loss (in absence of packet loss, TCP is exactly as "fast" as UDP), so if this is needed, there is no sane reason not to use TCP in the first place. It is a protocol that has been fine-tuned and worked reliably for literally billions of people for 4 decades.

Also, using one socket and one thread per client is possibly not the best approach. The disk won't read any faster, and the network card won't send any faster either. UDP doesn't need a socket per client either. When using TCP, you'll have no other choice but to use one socket per client, but still multiplexing using a readiness notification system will give you much better performance and fewer opportunities for threading errors.

Also, sending back a checksum such as one of the SHA family (or a MAC, if it needs to be secure) may be more efficient than echoing back the whole lot of data. The likelihood that the checksum matches and the data *accidentially* doesn't is neglegible.
Entire revision control systems that manage millions of lines of code for millions of people (such as git) rely on the fact that this just doesn't happen to identify files (well, it does happen of course, you just won't live to see it).

Comment: The first two conditions are only assured for single datagrams. Across an entire flow they aren't guaranteed at all, hence the requirement for sequence numbers, ACK or NACK, retransmission, etc. The maximum payload for an IPv4 datagram is 65507 bytes, and the maximum practical payload is really more like 534.

Comment: @Damon: +1 for a detailed description. I have a little confusion here, does not UDP perform checksum itself? Do I have to do the checksum thing manually?

Comment: @AyeshaHassan: UDP performs a checksum (as does IP and all underlying packet layers like ethernet or ATM). This is a CRC, which is designed to detect bit errors, but it is not designed to be particularly strong against malicious modification (both in a sense of exploiting collisions or simply replacing the checksum in the header). For the "normal case" (accidential corruption) the built-in CRC is good enough. If you also want to protect against a hacker modifying data, you need to add something better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question here ? Why UDP why not TCP? especially when you are worried for packet order and data corruption. According to me(I may be wrong), UDP is good only when the data is timesensitive like video stream.

Secondly, yes there are other methods of checking integrity of transmitted data. Simplest may be checking the MD5 and SHA1 checksum.

Comment: You're right - this is almost guaranteed to be a bad idea if it's anything other than an academic assignment.

Comment: Actually the systems at which the application is implemented has very limited bandwidth, and TCP requires more bandwidth as compared to UDP + I want a communication protocol as fast as possible so UDP was the right choice for me.

Comment: According to me, it will not matter as the data is text file only. ANd even if UDP is faster(it is just because it doesnt provide any cross checks) look at the overhead of processing, and in the case of UDP you need to transmit it twice (from server once and then from client), what you can do is send data from server and then client receives complete data calculates the checksum and sends only checksum to server. Server validates the checksum only. SO transmission is reduced to half

Comment: @user1614217 : Thank you for the post. Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Does the procedure that I am using actually can check above mentioned 3 conditions in all scenarios?

yes

What could be other methods of checking communication protocol except the one I desgined i.e. Sending a text file and getting it echoed and then comparing.

It doesn't have to be a file, but it has to be something you can check once you get the response.  You could just generate some random data and hold on to it until you get the response.

You'd have to tell us what you really want to test.  If you are trying to make sure that UDP doesn't give you bad data or out of order data, you're using the wrong protocol.  You're not testing anything by seeing if you get the exact data in the exact order you send it over UDP except for the networking infrastructure you have in place.

You say you want to test your application for "all possible scenarios", but that doesn't even mean anything.  You're testing to see if a behavior that is part of the UDP specification exists and trying to see that it doesn't?  Well, it does.  Even if you never see it.